# match value2 in 2 files if value 1 is exact match

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, array

I have 2 files containing list. Column 1 is userIds & column 2 is associated values

```
# cat file1
e3001 75
n5244 30
w1453 500

#cat file2
d1128 30
w1453 515
n5244 30
e3001 55
```

Things to consider.

1. userIds may not be sorted exactly in both files
2. Number of userIds may vary in files

REQUIRED

- firstly, userId from file1:column1 must match UserId in
  file2:column1
- next compare their values in file1:column2 with file2:column2
- print where values has variance. also extra userIds if
  any

OUTPUT:

```
e3001 has differnece, file1 value: 75 & file2 value: 55
w1453 has differnece, file1 value: 500 & file2 value: 515
d1128 is only present in filename: file1|file2
```

solution with 1liner-awk or bash loop is welcome

I'm trying to loop, but it's spitting garbage, guess there's some mislogic

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## VARIABLES
FILE1=file1
FILE2=file2
USERID1=(`awk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }' ${FILE1}`)
USERID2=(`awk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }' ${FILE2}`)
USERDON1=(`awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 }' ${FILE1}`)
USERDON2=(`awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 }' ${FILE2}`)

for user in ${USERID1[@]}
do
    for (( i = 0; i < "${#USERID2[@]}"; i++ ))
    #for user in ${USERID2[@]}
    do
        if [[ ${USERID1[$user]} == ${USERID2[i]} ]]
        then
            echo ${USERID1[$user]} MATCHES BALANCE FROM ${FILE1}: ${USERDON1[$i]} WITH BALANCE FROM ${FILE2}: ${USERDON2[$i]}
        else
            echo ${USERID1[$user]} 
        fi
    done
done
```

Below is copied file right from linux box. It's tab separated, but awk works with tab also, as far as I know.

```
#cat file1
e3001   55
n5244   30
w1453   515
```

Comment: Anything you tried and got stuck?

Comment: @RudiC Hi Rudic, I updated what I'm trying in code, but short of some logic I guess

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names in awk or shell to avoid clashes with builtin names and obfuscate your code. See [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm - your script takes the scenic route, so to speak. How about a simple `awk` approach? Like

```
awk '
NR==FNR         {ARR[$1] = $2
                 F1      = FILENAME
                 next
                }
($1 in ARR)     {if ($2 != ARR[$1]) print $1 " has difference," \
                                          F1 " value: " ARR[$1] \
                                          " & " FILENAME " value: " $2 
                 delete ARR[$1]
                 next
                }
                {print $1 " is only present in filename: " FILENAME
                }
END             {for (a in ARR) print a " is only present in filename: " F1
                }
' file[12]
d1128 is only present in filename: file2
w1453 has difference, file1 value: 500 & file2 value: 515
e3001 has difference, file1 value: 75 & file2 value: 55
```

It reads all of file1 into an array, then, with every line in file2, checks `$1` against the array indices, and, if present, prints the difference (or doesn't print if none), and `delete`s the array element (that `delete` may be missing in some awk implementations, BTW). If not present, print accordingly. In the `END` section, all remaining array elements are printed as they exist only in file1.

Comment: In my case, it's only printing this line ```d1128 is only present in filename: file2```

Comment: What `awk` version do you use? Did you copy the script verbatim?

Comment: I'm on RockyLinux8 and it has GNU awk version 4.2.1

Comment: Sollosa: With your NEW file1 (that from the third edit), there's NO differences; just the d1128 is missing! That's why my as well as @terdon 's approach are outputting just that line! What if you run it with your initial file1?

Comment: I really want to upvote this answer instead of posting my own that's the same approach but your insistence on using all upper case variable names is a real show-stopper. Since multiple people have already suggested you not use all upper case variable names and you keep doing it anyway there's no point commenting about that again so unfortunately I guess all I can do is post my own very similar answer..

Answer (score 2):

[The shell is a horrible tool for this sort of thing.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C112.4648) Also, as a general rule, you should avoid CAPS for your shell variables in your shell scripts. Since, by convention, global environment shell variables are capitalized, this can lead to naming collisions and hard to debug issues. Finally, your script requires reading the file 4 separate times(!) and *then* processing the data.

With that said, here's another awk approach (frankly, [RudiC's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698674/22222) is better, but I'd already written this so I'm posting anyway):

```
$ awk '{
  if(NR==FNR) {
    fn1=FILENAME;
    f1[$1]=$2;
    next
  }
  f2[$1]=$2;
  if($1 in f1){
    if($2 != f1[$1]){
      printf "%s is different; %s value: %s & %s value: %s\n", \
             $1,fn1,$2,FILENAME,f1[$1]
    }
  }
  else{
    print $1,"is only present in filename:", FILENAME
  }
}
END{
  for(id in f1){
    if( !(id in f2) ){print id,"is only present in afilename:",fn1}
  }
}' file1 file2
d1128 is only present in filename: file2
w1453 is different; file1 value: 515 & file2 value: 500
e3001 is different; file1 value: 55 & file2 value: 75
```

Comment: Don't see `c[...]` used any further after being incremented?

Comment: Thanks, @RudiC, that was a remnant from a different approach I'd tried. Fixed now. Sadly, I didn't think of `del` to clear the element from the array so your approach is much cleverer and more elegant.

Comment: Still printing only 1 line.

Comment: @Sollosa then your files are not as you show. Are these Windows text files, perhaps? Did you ever open them on a Windows machine? Do they have `\r` characters? Try `sed -n '/\r/p' file1 file2`, if that prints anything, you need to remove the `\r` characters.

Comment: @terdon no such characters, even files created on linux, I even tried to add FS as tab in begin section but no luck. I'll copy paste sample in below section of my question from my linux vm.

Comment: @Sollosa are you _sure_ there are only two fields in the file? Could you have stray `\t` characters in there? You can investigate with `od -c file1`.

Comment: @terdon
this is the output for command
```0000000   e   3   0   0   1  \t   5   5  \n   n   5   2   4   4  \t   3
0000020   0  \n   w   1   4   5   3  \t   5   1   5  \n
0000034```

Comment: @Sollosa OK, the issue seems to be that some of this (`FILENAME`, I think) is GNU-awk specific. Do you have `gawk`? This is why you must _always_ mention your operating system. I'm guessing this isn't Linux. This will work if you try with `gawk`. Sorry about that, answer clarified (stated that it requires gawk).

Comment: @terdon according to Sollosa comment on RudiC answer the OS is RockyLinux8 and `awk` is `GNU awk`

Comment: There is nothing gawk-specific in your script, it'll behave the same with any awk.

Comment: @Sollosa you showed the output of `od -c file1` and that has no problems so the issue must be with `file2` so show the output of `od -c file2`.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried it with busybox `awk` and got the output the OP was describing. Of course, I now see that was because I was using the new file, which only has one difference, but I hadn't realized it at the time. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon fellows I'm not even using any variables, just created 2 files, and running your commands as is.

Answer (score 2):

Comment are self explanatory :

```c
awk '
    BEGIN {file1 = ARGV[1]; file2 = ARGV[2]}

    # Load all file1 contents
    NR == FNR {map[$1] = $2; next}
    
    # If $1 is not in m then this key is unique to file2
    !($1 in map) {uniq[$1]; next}

    # If $1 is in m and the value differs there are delta
    # between the two files. Save it.
    $1 in map && map[$1] != $2 {diff[$1] = $2; next}

    # The two files have all the same data.
    {delete map[$1]}

    END {
        # Anything is in diff are in both files but
        # with different values
        for ( i in diff )
            print i, "has difference,", file1, "value:", map[i], "&", file2, "value:", diff[i]

        # Anything is still in m is only in file 1
        for ( i in map )
            if (!(i in diff))
                print i, "is only present in filename :", file1

        # Anything is in uniq is unique to file2
        for ( i in uniq )
            print i, "is only present in filename :", file2
    }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'function printUniq(Id, fName){
         printf("%s is only present in filename: %s\n", Id, fName)
}

{ fileName[nxtinput+0]=FILENAME }
!nxtinput{ Ids[$1]=$2; next }

($1 in Ids){ if($2!=Ids[$1])
                 printf ("%s has difference, %s value: %s & %s value: %s\n",\
                 $1, fileName[0], Ids[$1], fileName[1], $2);
             delete Ids[$1];
             next
}
{ printUniq($1, fileName[1]) }
END{ for(id in Ids) printUniq(id, fileName[0]) }' file1 nxtinput=1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same solution as posted by RudiC but without the all upper case variable names and with a couple of other minor improvements to clarity:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    file1[$1] = $2
    next
}
$1 in file1 {
    if ( $2 != file1[$1] ) {
        printf "%s has difference, %s value: %s & value: %s\n", $1, ARGV[1], file1[$1], FILENAME, $2
    }
    delete file1[$1]
    next
}
{
    print $1, "is only present in filename:", FILENAME
}
END {
    for ( id in file1 ) {
        print id, "is only present in filename:", ARGV[1]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
d1128 is only present in filename: file2
w1453 has difference, file1 value: 500 & value: file2
e3001 has difference, file1 value: 75 & value: file2
```